# Conversion from const char[] to class with constructor from string

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I try to pass a string to a function instead an object of class `A`, but I get an error.
Why is it not working and how can I make it work?

```
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A(const std::string &str) {

    }
};

void test(const A &a) {

}

int main()
{
    A a("abc"); //it's ok
    test(a); //it's ok
    test("abc"); //error?
    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to pass a string object to `test` like `test(std::string("abc"))`. I need convert it from const char*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) sequence of one type to another, there is a rule that states: At most, only one user defined conversion can be applied.  In

```
test("abc");
```

You need two user defined conversions.  First you need to conversion from `const char[N]` to `std::string`, which is considered a user defined conversion<sup>1</sup>.  Then you need to convert that `std::string` to a `A`, which would be a second user defined conversion.  That is the reason you get the error

---

To fix, you can use

```
test(A("abc"));
//or
test(std::string("abc"));
```

and now you have one explicit user defined conversion, and one implicit conversion, satisfying the one implicit conversion rule.

You could also provide a constructor for `A` that accepts a `const char*` so that you can directly convert from `"abc"` to an `A`.

---

1: Even though `std::string` is part of the standard library, it is not a "built in" type, but a library type.  This means it is counted as a user defined type, even though it shipped with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the standard only allow *direct* implicit conversions.

The following conversions are defined: `const char*` -> `std::string` and `const std::string` -> `A`

That means that you can safely pass a `const std::string` where a `A` is expected, but not an implicitly convertible to `std::string` object. Transitivity does not work here.

So you will have to do:

```
test(std::string("abc"));    // ok...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the conversions. "There can be only one" user defined conversion.

Here is :

```
 const char * -> std::string -> A
```

So you need to remove a conversion.
A way to fix it is to add the suffix 's' at the the end of the string :

```
test("ABC"s);
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Another way is to add the function :

```
void test(const std::string& s)
{
    test(A(s)) ;
}
```