Why is the compiler chosing a different constructor in implicit conversion?
I'm writing a program to better understand implicit and explicit conversion in c++ and I've came up with this simple code:
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

class Entity
{
public:
    int age;
    std::string name;
    Entity(const std::string& name) : name(name), age(-1) {}
    Entity(const int age) : age(age), name("Unknown") {}    
};

void printEntity(const Entity& e)
{
    std::cout << std::format("Age: {}, Name: {}\n", e.age, e.name);
}

int main()
{
    Entity a = 35;
    printEntity(a);

    Entity b = "mr someone";
    printEntity(b);

    printEntity(23);

}

which when compiling with g++ xplicit.cpp --std=c++23 gives the error:
xplicit.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
xplicit.cpp:25:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   25 |     Entity b = "mr someone";
      |                ^~~~~~~~
      |                |
      |                const char*

I've read in another answer here in stackoverflow that for Entity b declaration to work I'd have to have a constructor for Entity that receives const char* as parameter. However, I was watching a videotutorial where the guy wrote the code exaclty as this and it worked for him, Entity b was declared with no error. But why is it trying to convert to int and not to std::string&?
EDIT
After adding -fpermissive the behavior changed. From error to just a warning, however it seems that it have chosen a default constructor because of the output was:
Age: 35, Name: Unknown
Age: -1374514851, Name: Unknown // entity b
Age: 23, Name: Unknown


side note: it works with him because he is using msvc, it doesn't work on gcc or clang, note that msvc has a history of not sticking to the c++ standard, so i would say this is likely not standard C++

Doesn't work in Visual Studio 2022 for me with /permissive-. It does work without that flag. shrug #include <string> is missing although adding it does not solve the problem.

@RetiredNinja you need to remove the fmt stuff and use c++14 or c++17, it is likely that something in c++20 made this not possible for msvc

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67637307/conversion-from-const-char-to-class-with-constructor-from-string

change Entity b = "mr someone"; to Entity b{"mr someone"};

@AhmedAEK If I start removing things and changing the C++ version it becomes a different question doesn't it?

@RetiredNinja the question is, why it works in the video, that's what the video does, i am leaving the answer to whoever could know what in the C++20 standard that caused MSVC to change its behavior.

@DanielA.White I see that there is 2 conversions (from char -> str -> entity) but I was trying to understand why it worked in the video. I think that different compilers make sense

@AhmedAEK "The /permissive- option is implicitly set by the /std:c++latest option starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, and in version 16.11 by the /std:c++20 option. " from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170

Another alternative suggestion to my earlier suggestion, is to do a using std::string_literals::operator""s; (see Using string literals without using namespace std) then change your Entity b = "mr someone"; to Entity b = "mr someone"s;.  Both suggestions fix the underlying problem, although there are still clearly a lot of problems with the rest of the code, but would take far too much time than I have now to detail all the problems I see.
